# How to Calculate the new AWS EBS gp3 Cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm confused because of the [AWS price examples](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) in AWS, I think it's not clear enough because the 2000 GB in gp2 costs $200 in the AWS Calculator

Anyway, as I understand the cost,

The next gp3 will cost (**$2.4 / Month**)? (0.08 * 30GB/Month)

[image: 30 GB / 3000 IOPS / 125 MB/s]

And Here will costs (**$3.95 / Month**) ?

[image: 40 GB / 6000 IOPS / 250 MB/s]

```
$3.2 = (0.08 * 40GB/Month)
+
$0.5 = (0.005 * 6000-3000 FREE * 86400 sec/day) / (86400 sec/day * 30 Day)
+
$0.25 = (0.06 * 250-125 FREE * 86400 sec/day) / (86400 sec/day * 30 Day)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined by the [help]. This is a question for AWS Billing Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first calculation (30GB for $2.40) appears correct.

For the second example, it would appear that you copied the sample calculations from the [Amazon EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) page. In that example, the disk only exists for 12 hours rather than a whole month. That's why it includes the 86400 calculation.

If you are wanting to calculate the price for a whole month, then it would be:

```
40GB storage = 40 * .08 = $3.20 per month
+
6000 IOPS = 3000 Free + 3000 * $0.005 = $15 per month
+
250 MB/s Throughput = 125MB/s free + 125 * $0.04 = $5 per month
=
$23.20 per month
```

Comment: I think it's very expensive than AWS calculation lol :) The AWS example with 10,000 IOPS costs 58 Cents :)

Comment: Their example says "let’s say that you provision a 2000 GB volume for 12 hours (43,200 seconds) in a 30-day month". Thus, it is only for half a day, not a whole month.

Comment: YUP, But my EBS 30 GB only, and In case you calculate their example for the 24 hours it will be $1.1 only .. And I think there's something wrong in their calculation, they missed the main cost of 2000 GB * 0.08 which is $160 fixed

Comment: They did include the cost for 2000GB, but it was only calculated for 12 hours, not a full month ($2.667).

Comment: YEAH, That what I missed, Thanks man :) So my second example is wrong .. but the first one is correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that your 30GB $2.40 example is correct.

Comment: Thanks pal, Can you edit your answer with the first one is correct and the other is not to Mark as a solution? Thanks